# Regarding usage of generics in java

Tags: java, generics

While learning spring batch, I encountered a line as below:

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Integer, Integer>chunk(3).reader(new MyReader)..
```

Normally, in generics, we will have class name followed by `<>`. Example `List<Integer>`
But what does `.<Integer, Integer>chunk(3)` mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `chunk` *method* is generic instead of the *type* that `get` returns.

Comment: ok, got it. The API method signature is like: **public <I, O> SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk(CompletionPolicy completionPolicy)**  Thanks for clarification.  I never used the method call like that before.

Comment: @sai This is called a _type witness_. It is not normally necessary, but in some cases the compiler can't figure out the correct types to use, and you have to tell it.